# foreach in foreach php two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table

My problem is that my code always starts at the first position. So I can't give each line it's input field with the relating id.

```
foreach ($phase as $line) {
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo "<div class='headliner-th'><b>".$line['title']."</b></div>";
    echo "</td>";?>
    <?php foreach($items as $i=>$item): ?>
        <td><?= $form->field($item,"[$i]content")->textInput(['maxlength' => 200])->label(false); ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo "</tr>";
}
```

So how can I avoid to get the same input field again when it comes to a new row?

Comment: `<?phpecho "</tr>";` -> `<?php echo "</tr>";`

Comment: corrected it but wasn't the main issue ;)

Comment: how do you get the relating id? So, how is the $item in $items related with $line in $phase?

Comment: phases are the head of each line and the $item variable is for each input field in this row. Those fields also have a relation to a foreach with th cells

Answer (score 1):

The inner `foreach` loop always loops over the same variable `$items`. Shouldn't it be something that is somehow cycled through by the outer foreach?

Comment: okay so when i would count my array $items and would populate it within the foreach with a while by adding i++ you mean?

Comment: This depends heavily on how your $items are prepared. Without knowing how you create $items it's not possible to argue.
Could you post var_dump($phase) and var_dump($items)?

Comment: $items is a multidimensional array like this:
[1]=>array('title' => 'First Title', 'content' => 'blabla')[2]... and so on

Comment: ... and the [1], [2], etc. are related to a) the number of fields in a <tr> or b) the number of <tr>'s? I'm guessing the former (a) which means you just don't have the information in your $items that you desire. In other words: your items is two dimensional while it should be three dimensional.

Comment: Exactly my "item" is two dimensional and an object because it is build like Active Records in RoR and it is a multi model for collecting data.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with multiple if cases. It seems a bit dirty but easier than harass my object. So it looks like this: I hope anybody can use it: It is important to pre sort the object firstly on row than on col

```
<table class="sal-list" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<?php
    $width = 100/(count($pos)+1);
    echo "<th style='width:".$width."%;'></th>";
    foreach ($pos as $item) {
        echo "<th style='width:".$width."%;'><div class='headliner-th'>".$item['title']."</div></th>";
    }
?>
</tr>
<?php
$g = 0;
foreach ($phase as $line) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<div class='headliner-th'><b>".$line['title']."</b></div>";
        echo "</td>";?>
            <?php foreach($items as $i=>$item): ?>
                <?php if (($g <= count($items)) and ($g == $i) and ($line['id'] == $item['phas_id'])) : ?>
                    <td><?= $form->field($item,"[$i]content")->textInput(['maxlength' => 200])->label(false); ?></td>
                <?php $g++; endif;?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```